How can I trigger Toast before window.onbeforeunload?
I have the following small snippet of JavaScript, which works excellent to pop an alert when somebody might be leaving the form, while incomplete. However, I'm trying to first trigger a Toast with some small additional information that all works will be lost when continuing.
I'm unable to show the Toast before the window alert though, so it pops up only after. What would be a way to go about this? It's not that they would have to interact with the Toast yet; I just want the small alert in the bottom right of the screen indicating that process will be lost.
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    console.log(window.in_progress);
    const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')
    const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)
    toast.show()
    if(window.in_progress > 0){
        console.log(window.in_progress);
        return true;
    };   
};
</script>


nothing. you can't run code before browser

Makes sense.
Thought perhaps with a delay or something in the code it would be possible.

Your code doesn't pop an alert and prevent page closure.

Related: Why don't browsers support custom onbeforeunload message?

I can't find the alert() call in your code. Nonetheless, your problem is likely that the alert shows up before the toast animates, so the solution is to fire the alert after the toast finishes its animation. Add the below snippet somewhere in your code (make sure it only runs once, as it will append a new event listener to the toast each time it is called):
toast.addEventListener('shown.bs.toast', () => { // This runs after the toast becomes visible to the user
  // Fire the alert here
  alert("Your alert text");
})

update
It looks like there is no way to stay on the page while preventing the native browser pop-up [2], meaning that there is no way to fully animate the toast before the pop-up is shown.
I also considered creating a custom pop-up after the toast shows; however, there is no way to know the user's destination in order to proceed there when confirm is clicked [3].
Given all the above, the only solution I can think of is to cancel the toast's animation altogether by adding the data-bs-animation="false" attribute to the toast's HTML [4], which should allow it to show before the pop-up does.

if(window.in_progress > 0){
console.log(window.in_progress);
return true;
};
This piece prevents the browser from leaving the page, unless the user specifically confirms it.

I see (this was new to me). I updated my answer with more details, but the short conclusion is that the only option I could find is to cancel the toat's animation.

I think when OP says "alert" they are referring to the native alert modal shown by the browser that asks the user to confirm they want to navigate away from the page.
